# Problem with code for numerical integration in matlab.

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab, utility

Hi I have problem with calculating this expected utility with means of numerical integration, using matlab. The matrix stock data is a 1000x8 matrix with columns representing 7 stocks (columns 2-8, where the first column is the date of the measurments) I want first to calculate the integral for column 2. (The rest I can do by myself). The problem is that I get an expected utility in the order of -1.6524e-22, which is way wrong. It should be something like 1.0e-4.

Thanks in advance in any help in doing this.

The integral I am trying to calculate:

\begin{equation}U_\pi(w)=\int_{-0.2}^{0.2} (1-e^{(-kx)}) \frac{1}{\sqrt2\hat{\sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{(x-\hat{\mu})^2}{2\hat{\sigma^2}}}dx 
\end{equation}

And the code:

k=1;

s=1000;

stocks_data=stockdata(:,2:8); 
log_stock_data_matrix=log(stocks_data);

log_return_matrix=(log_stock_data_matrix(2:s,:)-log_stock_data_matrix(1:s-1,:))./(log_stock_data_matrix(1:s-1,:));

phat=mle(log_return_matrix(:,1));
mu_hat=phat(1);
sigma_hat=phat(2)
k=1

b=0.15;
a=-0.15;
F=@(x)(1-exp(-k.*x)).*(1/(sqrt(2*pi)*sigma_hat)).*exp(-((x-mu_hat).^2)/(2*sigma_hat.^2))
Expected_utility = quad(F,a,b)

Comment: It is difficult to help without any explanation of what equations you are trying to solve. Anyways, there is a syntax error in the definition of F, which may or may not be your problem: k.x

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I agree and have included it by now.

Comment: There are different ways to calculate an integral with Matlab: "integral", "trapz"... they do not systematically give the same result.